# Deserialize byte array into class whose name is given as String

Tags: generics, java-8, deserialization

I have data that is serialized from a java object(there can be different types of objects), I also have the fully qualified class name of the type of the serialized data in String format.
Now I want a generic method(non-generic already working) to which I will pass the String formatted class name and byte array data and in return, it will return the deserialized class object. somewhat similar to below signature

```
public <T> T convertByteArrayToObject(String className, byte[] data);
```

eg, If I pass `convertByteArrayToObject("java.lang.String", [65, 66, 67])`;

then it should return "ABC" as String object(but custom types should also be applicable).

Thanks

Comment: Then you have to implement that method, the same way you implemented the other method which creates byte arrays from arbitrary objects.

Comment: I think you can do something like this `public static <T> T convertByteArrayToObject(String className, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        Constructor<?> c = Class.forName(className).getConstructor(byte[].class);
        return (T) c.newInstance(data);
    }`; but that cast to `T` is well, useless. I don't think this is doable in a generic way, so that you know your types at compile time; I mean you know the `className` at runtime anyway

Comment: @Holger but that is still not possible in a generic way right? I mean the type of `className` is known only at runtime, I see no way to enforce this at compile time

Comment: @Eugene you can declare a method like `public <T> T convertByteArrayToObject(Class<T> expectedType, byte[] data)`, but it’s not clear how the magic inside the method is supposed to work. If I know the expected type beforehand (at compile-time), I could write, e.g. `new String(byteArray)` in the first place. Not that relying on the default charset is recommended…

Comment: @Holger well the OP does not know the class until runtime, I suppose that is why it passes the `className`, no knowledge of `Class<T>` yet and the magic is probably just triggering the constructor, if such is available

Comment: @Eugene if you don’t know the type at compile-time, there is no point in trying to make it generic, as the only purpose of Generics is to provide you a compile-time type.

Comment: @Holger that was my entire point :) thank you. I don't think the OP understand this

Comment: Thank you guys(@Eugene, @Holger) for explaining the concept patiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it, you want a generic method - so that it could enforce some type safety *at compile time*, but you only have your `className` at runtime; this is simply not possible or you don't understand the problem really. You can pretend it to be generic, for example:

```
public static <T> T convertByteArrayToObject(String className, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
    Constructor<?> c = clazz.getConstructor(byte[].class);
    return (T) c.newInstance(data);
}
```

But that cast is useless and your method really returns just `Object`, so you can assign that in the callers to whatever you want:

```
Integer s = convertByteArrayToObject("java.lang.String", new byte[] { 65, 6, 67 });
```

So this *would compile just fine*, giving you a fake impression of type safety. The callers on the other hand, *at runtime*, will fail; since there are `checkcast` calls inside the byte code of them. Stick to whatever you have and do proper instance of checks.

Comment: Hi, I understand your point here. But will it make a difference if all the possible values of T/className will be implementing the Serializable interface for sure?

Comment: @Jayesh unfortunately no, you could declare `<T extends Serializable>` and after erasure it would be `Serializable`, but that does not help you much

Comment: Thanks @Eugene, I understood the concept you were trying to explain here. So what I have done is I have created one custom marker interface and all the classes that I want to deserialize must be implementing this interface. So now I know, at compile time, that which class it needs to be deserialized to. Then I used `instanceof` check to typecast to correct class. Which worked for me.